# What is the impact of using complex words on the paper acceptance probability?

Tags: publications, writing-style, reference-request

*Oppenheimer, Daniel M. "[Consequences of erudite vernacular utilized irrespective of necessity: Problems with using long words needlessly.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=18327303614821613289&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" Applied Cognitive Psychology 20, no. 2 (2006): 139-156.* looked at the impact of using complex words on the graduate admission probability.

Is there any research/study/survey that looked at the impact of using complex words on the paper acceptance probability?

I am most interested in the field of computer science, and English-speaking venues.

Comment: Is there any dataset of submitted papers, labeled with editor decision (accept, reject, revision)? that would be a fun dataset to play with.

Comment: @ff524 yes such a dataset would be interesting, I'm looking for that as well: [Does any publication venue make rejected papers available for download?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/42753/452)

Comment: I don't know of any study like this, but I'd be surprised if there was a correlation. Sometime a complex word is a *precise* word, and therefore it adds clarity to the narrative. Other times, a complex word is nothing but a fancy word that obfuscates meaning. Above all, authors should strive to communicate clearly. Hopefully, referees judge papers based on the quality of the research and the clear understandability of the presented findings, and wouldn't be easily influenced by the injection of highfalutin synonyms.

Comment: @ff524, fun yes. Available, hopefully not, at the very least for privacy reasons.

Comment: @vonbrand what's the privacy issue?

Comment: May I add that we should write to our audience. I have no data either, but writing for a low level journal in a specific discipline would entail use of obscure vocabulary "of necessity." Writing the same narrative for a higher level journal with broader reach would necessitate more accessible vocabulary. Another interesting confound if that dataset is ever discovered.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If nothing else, at least some journals/conferences explicitly say that submissions (accepted or rejected) will be kept in strict confidence. So it goes to "reasonable expectation of privacy". Ethically it would also be highly dubious to release personally-identifiable data without the informed consent of the people who've submitted research data. It would also be an issue of copyright in many cases, as copyright transfers/licenses aren't given for rejected papers. A journal/conference could always change their conditions of submission to allow this in the future, of course.

Comment: Related (off site): [Research papers containing abstracts that are shorter and consist of more commonly used words accumulate citations more successfully](http://retractionwatch.com/2016/03/10/papers-with-simpler-abstracts-are-cited-more-study-suggests/).

Comment: I agree with @J.R. that complex words sometimes add clarity and sometimes are merely pompous or serve to obfuscate.  I would add that referees should be able to tell the difference and might therefore be influenced either positively or negatively by such words.  Personally, I get annoyed by overly pompous prose. I don't think it would cause me to reject a paper outright, but it might make me more sensitive to other faults in the paper.

Comment: @ff524, a contradictory study.  http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004205

Comment: Similar question:  http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65666/which-is-better-a-paper-with-pedantic-vocabularies-or-a-paper-easy-to-read/65668#65668

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reply directly to your question on complex words, but it appears that complex (long) titles are associated with fewer citations (see [Deng](http://www.nature.com/news/papers-with-shorter-titles-get-more-citations-1.18246)). So, you might extrapolate that complex words are going to decrease the likelihood of citations and, further extrapolating, possibly also of acceptance.